# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement multithreading invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, objectlistview

I want to get subitem[7].text from [objectlistview](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)

form another thread.
Error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Problematic line:

```
string url = objectListView1.Invoke(new Action(() => 
objectListView1.SelectedItems[objectListView1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[7].Text));
```

C# code:

```
void getThumbnail()
{
    try
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        string url = objectListView1.Invoke(new Action(() => 
        objectListView1.SelectedItems[objectListView1.SelectedIndex].SubItems[7].Text));
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldoc = web.Load(url);
        htmldoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

        var link = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//link[@itemprop='thumbnailUrl']");
        var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
        pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Load(href)));
    }
    catch (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWebException)
    {

    }
}
private void objectListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thr = new Thread(() => getThumbnail());
    thr.Start();
}
```

Comment: Not even the basic courtesy of telling us **which line causes the problem**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string url = objectListView1.Invoke(new Action(() => 
       objectListView1.
       SelectedItems[objectListView1.SelectedIndex].
       SubItems[7].Text));
```

[`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate doesn't return any result. If you want to return `string`,  then you need to use [`Func<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string url = objectListView1.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => 
       objectListView1.
       SelectedItems[objectListView1.SelectedIndex].
       SubItems[7].Text)) as string;
```